# How to calculate the outliers in a Pandas dataframe while excluding NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, z-score

I have a pandas dataframe that should look like this.

```
   X     Y     Z           Is Outlier
0  9.5 -2.3   4.13         False
1  17.5 3.3   0.22         False
2  NaN  NaN  -5.67         NaN
3  547.16  11.17  -288.67  True
4  -0.05  3.55  6.78       False
...
```

Some values in this dataframe are outliers. I came across this method of calculating the outliers in every colum using the z score:

```
df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

My goal is to create a column `Is Outlier` and put a True/False on each row that has/doesn't have at least one outlier and NaN for rows with at least one NaN value and, at the same time, keep a count of all "True" values.

This is my code so far.

```
dt = np.fromfile(path, dtype='float')
df = pd.DataFrame(dt.reshape(-1, 3), column = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Please provide a DataFrame constructor of the input (maybe more than 3 rows for a meaningful computation) and the matching expected output.

Comment: @mozway Check the edits..

Comment: @mozway Doine. The question is up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider NaN rows to be noise, you can compute the `zscore` dropping them, this will automatically give you NaNs when you assign the result:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

thresh = 1

df['Is Outlier'] = zscore(df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].dropna()).ge(thresh).any(1)
```

*NB. I used at threshold of `1` for the example here.*

Output:

```
        X      Y       Z Is Outlier
0    9.50  -2.30    4.13      False
1   17.50   3.30    0.22      False
2     NaN    NaN   -5.67        NaN
3  547.16  11.17 -288.67       True
4   -0.05   3.55    6.78      False
```

Alternatively, `zscore` has a `nan_policy='omit'` option, but this wouldn't directly give you NaN in the output. The zscore computation however will use all values, including those from NaN rows. (This makes no difference in the final result here).

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

thresh = 1

df['Is Outlier'] = (zscore(df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']], nan_policy='omit')
                    .ge(thresh).any(1)
                    .mask(df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].isna().any(1))
                    )
```

Output:

```
        X      Y       Z Is Outlier
0    9.50  -2.30    4.13      False
1   17.50   3.30    0.22      False
2     NaN    NaN   -5.67        NaN
3  547.16  11.17 -288.67       True
4   -0.05   3.55    6.78      False
```

Comment: What's `.ge()`?

Comment: The same as `≥`. Greater or equal.

Comment: Any way to get the count of all values in the Outlier column that are True? I want to know how many rows have outliers.

Comment: `df['Is Outlier'].sum()` or `df['Is Outlier'].value_counts(dropna=False)` to also count False/NaN.

Comment: Let me know which one of the zscore alternatives works for you.

Comment: Sorry. How to get all values that are false?

Comment: See edit above. Are you meaning the counts?

Comment: That edit outputs, false true and nan

Comment: Do you mean `df[df['Is Outlier'].eq(False)]`?